# about Soft Machine and Gong

Tags: history, jazz, prog-rock, reference-request

Is there a book or a source containing the whole history of Soft Machine and Gong? In particular focusing on the interaction between their members during the sixties and before their foundation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of searching *specifically* for literature concerning Soft Machine and Gong I suggest that you look into [The Canterbury Scene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canterbury_scene) instead.

> The Canterbury scene (or Canterbury Sound) is a subgenre of, or sibling to, progressive rock. The term describes a loosely defined style of music created by a number of improvisational musicians, some of whom were based in the city of Canterbury, Kent, England during the late 1960s and early 1970s. [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canterbury_scene)

There are various articles on the web such as:

[CANTERBURY SCENE : A Progressive Rock Sub-genre](https://www.progarchives.com/subgenre.asp?style=12)

[The Canterbury Scene: The Sound Of The Underground](https://www.loudersound.com/features/the-canterbury-scene-the-sound-of-the-underground)

And probably many more.